# Vaadin: how does @CssImport works among the views? it is a "global" import?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

If I have for example a view where I use

```
@CssImport(value = "somefile.css")
```

with `somefile.css` defined like

```
.test-foobar {

  color: green

}
```

I can use `.addClassName("test-foobar")` in any component in any view/class even if the class is NOT annotated with `@CssImport(value = "somefile.css")`.

It's like that once defined the `@CssImport` it's global available to all the views.

Other than hard-coding css definition in the class file for every component can you define a css rules in a file that is just imported and used for the view that is annotated with `@CssImport` ?

P.S. I am using vaadin 14 right now, but it is ok to have informations if it is different in 23+, just to know how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a global import and this is the intended behaviour as stated
in the
[docs](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.1.1/com/vaadin/flow/component/dependency/CssImport.html)

> NOTE: Currently all frontend resources are bundled together into one
> big bundle. This means, that CSS files loaded by one class will be
> present on a view constructed by another class. For example, if there
> are two classes RootRoute annotated with @Route(""), and another class
> RouteA annotated with @Route("route-a") and
> @CssImport("./styles/custom-style.css"), the custom-style.css will be
> present on the root route as well.

So from here, it's basically a question, of how drastic you need to
change the style between the views.

If it's minute things, on very few components, I'd stick with the global
CSS and sprinkle some class names where needed.

If you have massive changes, I'd go for a "sub theme".  Create your own
theme, and then separate the styling with
`[theme~="special-theme-for-a"]` selectors and setting the theme in your
view/router-layout.  Ideally you do this by just switching out some vars
at very high level.  You can take some hints from how light and dark is
done in the Lumo theme or how "theme variants" are done for many of the
existing components.

Also relevant:

- https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/application/styling
- https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/theme-variants
- https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/sharing-style-sheets

Comment: So where to place `@CssImport` ? just in a single view with all the rules ?  or just to make the code clear re-import it for every view just to know when you read the code that is used in that view ?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to not use it. You can place your css inside your theme folder and import it in your styles.css

Comment: TBH I have never bothered to check, whether adding the same CssImport multiple times would actually result in duplicate entries in the bundle - I'd _assume_ it's not the case.  But even if it is, it's just a bit of waste of traffic and client-resources. Put it where it makes the most sense to you: duplicate it on each view, if it helps you to remind things - or put it somewhere central. Or don't use it at all like @Knoobie suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I never used the theme setup, in my projects I use `@Theme(value = Lumo.class)` and in the various views `@CssImport`. I was thinking that creating a theme would mean to create the settings for all the components... I have to read about this type of setup. Or maybe I will ask another question to clarify this type of config.